# How do you enabled/disable retina display support at runtime?

Tags: ios, air

We need to deliver a single app which uses the retina display on the iPhone4 but not the iPod Touch, but the only way I can find to control the native resolution is the requestedDisplayResolution tag in the app descriptor.

Is there a way to change this at runtime using Actionscript or a native extension?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why would you purposefully degrade the experience of iPod Touch users?

Comment: Because the iPod Touch is underpowered and can't handle the game at retina resolution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope, by this time, you already have found the answer for your question. But I'll leave here an answer for those whom got here without a clue like me and you when you wrote it :)
This is the solution that worked for me: Exclude the iPad3 from high resolution in the app-description.xml

```
<requestedDisplayResolution excludeDevices="iPad3">high</requestedDisplayResolution>
```

Hope it works for you as the same it worked for me ;)

Answer (score -1):

You don't. There's no reason why you would want to degrade the experience for iPod Touch users. If you mean between older versions of the devices and newer (as in non-Retina and Retina), the device/app does it for you. There's no need to manually switch display resolutions except for OpenGL apps. And that's a totally different beast…

That being said, if there's some essential, compelling need for your display degradation, explain it more. If it's essential to the functioning of the app, Apple will probably allow it. However, if it is solely for a Lite version/something like that, it's likely they'll reject the app.

Comment: Just to repeat: The iPod Touch performs very poorly at retina display resolution so we have to resort to knocking it down to lower quality display in order for the game to run properly.

Comment: Rather than knocking down the entire resolution, just disable some effects/extraneous graphics if possible. I understand your need to improve the experience, but halving the display resolution is not the most elegant way to do it.

Comment: There is nothing extraneous to disable. There is a single performance bottleneck and it's because the game has anywhere between 2 and 5 images which are 720x720 moving around the screen at any given time. (There is no other way to implement the design I've been handed, before you ask)

Comment: Well, sounds like halving the resolution is your only option. That's too bad. I have no idea how to do that either. Sorry.